# Speed up the pattern match and replace in python for huge file

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, replace

I Have a very huge file (10Gb) which looks like this

```
ref     R       A       C       G       T
N       0       0       0       0       0
A       5       5       0       0       0
N       0       0       0       0       0
C       8       0       8       0       0
N       0       0       0       0       0
A       6       6       0       0       0
T       0       0       0       0       0
```

So for all the entries where R=0 and if the ref is A|C|G|T replace 0 with 25 in their respective columns. I want something that looks like below

```
ref     R       A       C       G       T
A       5       5       0       0       0
C       8       0       8       0       0
A       6       6       0       0       0
T       0       0       0       0       25
```

Here is what I tried. It works fine but takes too much time. Wanted to know if there is any faster way to do it

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("test",delimiter = "\t",header=0)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[index, 'R']==0:
        if df.loc[index, 'ref']=="A":
            df.loc[index, 'A_pp']=25
        if df.loc[index, 'ref']=="T":
            df.loc[index, 'T_pp']=25
        elif df.loc[index, 'ref']=="C":
            df.loc[index, 'C_pp']=25
        elif df.loc[index, 'ref']=="G":
            df.loc[index, 'G_pp']=25

df_filtered = df[df['ref']!= "N"]
df_filtered.to_csv('./test_formatted.txt', sep = "\t")
```

Comment: Why not use `dask` or `pyspark` as the data is huge?

Comment: I have no experience working with `dask` or `pyspark`. But will give it a try. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: I removed the `awk` tag because the question isn't about awk, even if a reasonable solution might be to use it (personally, I use Perl for "throw a block of text at something and slice and dice it", and the solution would be quite similar, but whatever floats your boat). I'll note that `pandas` isn't gaining you much here, and you might gain something from using the plain Python `csv` module, with a loop over `for row in csv.reader(fileobj, delimiter='\t'):` that reads a row and writes a row at a time, instead of slurping the whole file into memory as `pandas` is likely doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is not to use python at all. This is an awk specialty and will be orders of magnitude faster done in awk alone, e.g.

**Edit - Improved Efficiency**

```
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS="\t" } 
    FNR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
            h[$i] = ++n
        print
        next
    } 
    $1~/[ACGT]/ {
        if ($h[$1] == 0)
            $h[$1] = 25
        print
    }
' file
```

`awk` processes one record (line) at a time with each field available as `$1, ... $NF` (where `NF` is the number of fields). `awk` applies each of the rules you write in the order you write them. There are two special rules `BEGIN` and `END` that you can use for pre-post processing. All other rules are `condition { commands }` form where the condition can either be a REGEX, numeric or string conditional.

In addition to the `BEGIN` rule above (which simply sets the *Output Field Separator* (`OFS`) to `tab`), there are two rules. The first only applies to `FNR == 1` (File record number, e.g. line number `1`) to process the header, storing the header column values in the `h` indexed array and printing the header row. `next` simply skips all remaining rules and tells awk to start processing the next record (line).

The second rule matches when the first field (`$1`) matches the REGEX `[ACGT]`, when field 1 is one of `A`, `C`, `G` or `T` within the `[...]` character class. If it is, then it loops over the number of fields and checks which index in the `h` array matches the first field and if the value stored in the field is `0`. If so the value of the field is set equal to `25`. The line is printed.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file named `gene` you would have:

```
$ awk '
>     BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
>     FNR==1 {
>         for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
>             h[$i] = ++n
>         print
>         next
>     }
>     $1~/[ACGT]/ {
>         if ($h[$1] == 0)
>             $h[$1] = 25
>         print
>     }
> ' gene
ref     R       A       C       G       T
A       5       5       0       0       0
C       8       0       8       0       0
A       6       6       0       0       0
T       0       0       0       0       25
```

Look things over and let me know if I understood your replacement correctly or if not, drop a comment and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: Glad to help. awk is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing. It processes one record (line) at a time with each field available as $1, ... $NF (where NF is the number of fields). awk applies each of the rules you write in the order you write them. There are two special rules `BEGIN` and `END` that you can use for pre-post processing. All other rules are `condition { commands }` form. There are two above. Within the rules, the syntax is analogous to C roughly (meaning `{ ... }` block enclosure is required. And ... awk is blistering fast.

Comment: In fact, I'll edit and fix the indenting above so that is clear.

Comment: @Biofreek - I updated the answer adjusting how the `h` array was used to eliminate the loop in the second rule. That should provide a bit more efficiency reducing the runtime needed.